# URL rewrite rule conflits in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

I am getting problem in URL rewrite rules. 
I am used **UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter** Dll for Url rewriting in asp.net website.
I used rules name as "Advanced"
& Other rule name as DefaultRule that is used for any user profile page(ie. any user's profile page).
When I entered username as "**AdvancedMachinesTools**". 
**That Rules as below:-**

```
<urlrewritingnet rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true" contextItemsPrefix="QueryString" defaultPage="Login" xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
<rewrites>
    <add name="advanced" virtualUrl="^~/advanced" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/advancedSearch.aspx" ignoreCase="true"  />
    <add name="DefaultRule" virtualUrl="^~/(.*)" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/UserProfile.aspx?uname=$1" ignoreCase="true"/>
</rewrites>
</urlrewritingnet>
```

I got error message "File does not exist" I wrote DefaultRule at last in web.config file.

How I resolved it...?

**EDITED**

Examples
Suppose that my website url: www.abcd.com 
1) For advanced rule I wrote URL like this [www.abcd.com/advanced](http://www.abcd.com/advanced)
Rule:

```
<add name="advanced" virtualUrl="^~/advanced" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/advancedSearch.aspx" ignoreCase="true"  />
```

2) for Default user rule 
for suppose username: AdvancedEyecare it used default rule

```
 <add name="DefaultRule" virtualUrl="^~/(.*)" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/UserProfile.aspx?uname=$1" ignoreCase="true"/>
```

When I enter url like http://www.abcd.com/AdvancedEyecare
Then I got error "File not exist" because Rule used 1 advanced rule not used user default rule. I want to call userrule instead of 1 advanced rule.
How can solve it?

Comment: Do `~/UserProfile.aspx` exists? The rewrite rules changed quite dramatically from your previous Page1.aspx / Page2.aspx scenario.

Comment: Give some examples of (ORIGINAL ADDRESS -> REWRITTEN ADDRESS) pairs you need.

Comment: Hi @tiagoinu ~/UserProfile.aspx is exists.

Comment: Hi @tiagoinu Original file "~/AdvancedSearch.aspx" Rewrittern address  "^~/advanced"..

Comment: @Abhishek Could you add some expected rewrite examples to your question? I mean complete URLs, like "`http://domain.com/abc/dce` -> `http://domain.com/something?arg=else`".

Comment: Default Page Rule: http://domain.com/UserProfile.aspx?uname=AdvancedEyecare ->  http://domain.com/AdvancedEyecare  ...

Comment: @tiagoinu I first wrote advanced rule then wrote user default rule  [http://domain.com/advancedSearch.aspx](http://domain.com/advancedSearch.aspx) -> [http://domain.com/advanced](http://domain.com/advanced) that all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `$` at the end of the first pattern:

```
<add name="advanced" virtualUrl="^~/advanced$" destinationUrl="~/advancedSearch.aspx" />
```

This will *only* match `/advanced` and rewrite it to `/advancedSearch.aspx`:

```
http://www.abcd.com/advanced -> http://www.abcd.com/advancedSearch.aspx
```

---

The other rewrite you want is

```
http://www.abcd.com/AdvancedEyecare -> http://www.abcd.com/UserProfile.aspx?uname=AdvancedEyecare
```

Comment: Yes. "^" means the start of the address, and "$" means the end of it. (Regular expression syntax.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @tiagoinu Its great answer I appreciate your quiet support.. Good yaar.. Can we make friends?

Comment: @Abhishek Just curious, but are you using the Microsoft URL Rewrite module? http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: @Abhishek I asked because maybe you will want to configure rewriting.net to stop processing the next rules after the first match. I don't know how it works (the Microsoft one is simpler).

Comment: @Abhishek Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

At first I would change the order of the rewrite rules.

```
<rule name="GroupDefaultRule">
     <match url="Group" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="Page2.aspx?action=group" />
</rule>
<rule name="Group1Rule">
     <match url="(.*)/Group" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="page1.aspx?action=group&amp;uname={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Nevertheless, why would OlewinskiGroup be matched into "(.*)/Group" ? There is no slash present

Comment: Thanks @citronas Ans: Our requirement is that <username>/Group so we identify the group from that username so we need two separate rules. I tried Above code but not worked.. Is any another solution for that?